# How to automatically update term store data from lists?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, metadata, blog, tagging

I'm trying to create a system for metadata on my site, which has three lists acting as trackers (eg Consultants, Projects, Organizations). Those lists are used to organize files by lookup column, which works well.

To tie these different components I'm putting together a blog for updates, with comments possible for each entry.  I'll likely use SP's native blogging functions, but for it to work as desired I need to be able to filter by tags that are set dynamically by the aforementioned tracking lists (so that I can see all updates for just one project).

In other words, my managers should be able to create a new item on the "projects" list, and immediately post a blog entry using a corresponding tag.  As far as I can tell, this would require automatically updating the term store based on those lists, and I can't find a way to do this?

I'm not opposed to apps or programming either, so I'm open to any suggestions on how to automatically update the term store from lists. Alternatively, a suggestion on how else to create this type of functionality (tag-able blog posts with SP comments that use tags generated by lists). Only managed metadata please, I'm not dealing with 10 different spellings of the same thing!

SharePoint 365

Comment: How does creating an item in the "projects" list control the term? Same as title? User-specified? Can it be changes via projects list edit form? I think I know how to do this in SP 2013 on-prem, not sure if it is the same for 365/online.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use "item created" on the list as a trigger ( workflow or Flow) which will insert the ID and title as a new term in the term set.
If the postings are tagged with those managed metadata search and refiners will be easy as pie